# not called functions

Tags: arm, ghidra

trying to reverse a Cortex-M0 bin file using Ghidra.
There are functions that are Never Called any where in the code! (but actually  should be called somewhere !)
What could be the reasons?
Tnx

Comment: One possibility is that the code blocks/functions in which those function (that are "never called") are called but Ghidra wasn't able to identify them as code blocks and thus has not decoded them as ARM assembler functions.

Comment: If its a raw firmware file and doesn't have any fancy headers then its more than likely that a large part of the binary is undefined. It is often the case when reversing raw binary formats that one has to understand and define the structure themselves to correctly define undefine parts of the firmware.